# Launching a subprocess which survives parent process

Tags: java

I would like to start a subprocess from a JVM but I want this JVM to stop before the child process.

I tried it with the JRockit on Windows XP but it seems the JVM waits for the child process termination before ending itself.

Is there a way to start a child process which becomes independant of the parent process, i.e. which ends after the parent process ends ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[Spawn a process in Java that survives a JVM shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295736/spawn-a-process-in-java-that-survives-a-jvm-shutdown)

Standard Sun JVM doesn't wait for child processes to finish