# Create process that survives creator process

Tags: java

Is there a way to create a process from a java application, that can can survive the creator process?

I use ProcessBuilder to create child processes in my application, but I can't see a way to configure the process to survive the shutdown of my "main" application.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038223/launching-a-subprocess-which-survives-parent-process?rq=1 which will have links to other threads.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running another binary, processes started using exec would be created in a separate process:

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("yourprogram");`