# Web server throws error but application continues to run

Tags: tomcat, server, glassfish

I am new to a java project. I have been asked to terminate the server once web application throws http exception. I dont understand how to retrieve the ongoing server and then stop it through java code. In the project both glassfish and apache tomcat are being used. Would I need to stop the apache tomcat server or the glassfish server and how? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Normally if you find serious system problem you only need to restart the apache tomcat (step b).  But if you want to restart glassfish, please following (step a) below:

(Step a)
Restart the domain by using the restart-domain(1) subcommand.

e.g.

```
restart-domain mydomain4
```

or thru a browser

```
http://yourhost:4848/__asadmin/restart-domain
```

(Step B)
For restarting apache tomcat

```
systemctl restart identity_tomcat.service
```

Comment: thanks for your response. Actually I am looking for how to stop the server through the java code. Would I need any plugins and what syntax to use..

Comment: Oh you want to use java codes to do this instead of commands in console ? Then please refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48109709/restart-tomcat-with-java